# My Thunderbird removes the subscription of /some/ IMAP folders

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

Since several month I experience a very strange behavior in thunderbird: From time to time, **some of my IMAP folders I have subscribed to in thunderbird disappear**. They simply are no longer subscribed. I can manually subscribe to these folders again and they are downloaded and available ... until suddenly they miss again. I did not figure out yet, when this happens.

It's always the same set of folders that disappear, some email archives on a shared account.

I'm currently using TB 45.7.0.

Did someone experince the same behavior in TB?
I's appreciate any hints what the reason could be or how to identify the reason.
Thanks!

Comment: Choose "server settings" on account that misbehaving then press `advanced` button and uncheck box that says "Allow server to override these namespaces". I just guessing it is reset on a server side

Comment: This option was really checked. Let's see what happens. Thanks for your *very quick* help! I'd never had the idea to look at this setting ...

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it would work, I will move this solution to the answer then, so if somebody will step on same issue it would help them to find it

Comment: Your suggestion did not solve my issue.The folder keep disappearing :-(  ... I'd like to avoid having to create a completely new profile ...

Comment: Try to uncheck "Show only subscribed folders", it will tell TB to show all IMAP folders regardless subscription. I still think that subscriptions reseted on IMAP server

Comment: Ah, thanks, I try this now. Although this account has MANY folders ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution .... it seems that the subscriptions to the IMAP folders on our shared account are also shared among users. I discovered that a colleague was puzzled why his Thunderbird always "automatically" *subscribes* to these folders ...

Anyway, I did never expect that IMAP folder subscriptions could be shared.