# Thunderbird IMAP subscribing to folders: mail server responded "subscribe failed"

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I'm using Thunderbird with 2 different IMAP email providers. I've been using them for months. Recently though, when I start Thunderbird, my IMAP folders (apart from Inbox) have vanished. When I go through the "Subscribe" dialogue, I can see the folders listed, but subscribing has no effect, and in the activity manager I see

> "The current command did not succeed. The mail server for the account *** responded: subscribe failed"

This message appears once for every folder I attempt to subscribe to.

I've tried deleting my local Thunderbird MSF files, and restarting - no change. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.02 with Thunderbird 78.11.0 (from the standard repository).

How can I get my IMAP folders successfully subscribed?

> *Update: following [this SU tip](https://superuser.com/questions/1177430/my-thunderbird-removes-the-subscription-of-some-imap-folders#comment1707716_1177430) I un-ticked "Show only subscribed folders" which at least allows me to see all my folders. I'd quite like to solve the problem directly though.*

Comment: If nothing changed on your end, have you tried asking the mail provider if they have changed anything that might cause this ?

Comment: @Silbee Good point - I was about to respond that these are 2 different mail providers, but in fact they're both Microsoft under the hood... so perhaps something did change